# docker ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, docker, pip, alpine-linux, python-3.9

hey guys getting this error when i try to `docker image build -t py-test`

**ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp_ohy_f6g/output.json'**

**executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install ibm-db]: exit code: 1**

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.13-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install ibm-db
RUN pip install flask
EXPOSE 8080
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "output.py"]
```

Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414

macOS (localhost) version -- macos montery version 12.4 (21F79)

Answer (score 1):

After running the build with `pip` in verbose mode (`pip install -v ibm-db`), you can see the following error:

```
No Gcc installation detected.
Please install gcc and continue with the installation of the ibm_db.
```

`ibm-db` requires you to have `gcc` available when installing it, so that you can build it's C modules.

Installing `gcc` and `libc-dev` before `ibm-db` solves the issue:

```
FROM python:3.9.13-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add gcc libc-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install ibm-db
RUN pip install flask

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "output.py"]
```